# How would a Minecraft server run on these 2 PC's?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, windows, windows-xp

I have two PC's that are sitting in the basement doing nothing, they both work very well considering their age.

Specs-

The custom Dell PC has an Intel Celeron Processor, 465 MHz, 512 MB of RAM, running Windows XP 2002 Service Pack 3. The Ultra PC has an Intel Pentium II Processor, 350 MHz, an absolutely stunning 144 MB of RAM, running Windows XP 2002 Service Pack 3 as well.

So what I was wondering was if either of both of these computers could handle hosting a 1.10.2 minecraft server for 4-10 people (4 people is the absolute minimum). What would the lag be like? Would it be block lag (having to break a block multiple times) or frame rate lag?

I just want to know if this would be possible and if it is, what the condition of this hypothetical server would be. Thanks!

P.S. Also, and this is a stretch, I know, but would this server be able to handle about 5 Forge mods?

Comment: Short answer: no, they won't work.  In fact, those PCs aren't much good for anything beyond a basic ftp or email server.

Comment: Ok I normally use them for hosting web servers and playing old games like Star Trek Voyager Elite Force.

Comment: @R2bEEaton_ - Minecraft servers require at least a [Core 2 Duo & 2GB of RAM](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Server/Requirements#Running_a_LAN_Party_type_Server_.28since_1.3.2.29), and that's the low end of the spectrum. I'm afraid Minecraft is just too new for your PCs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not. Ram is what matters most for servers, and 512 MB of ram is simply not enough for forge mods.

It may just barely work for 4 people, but it will lag **a lot**. You're better off buying a cheap desktop from /r/hardwareswap or ebay and running it off there.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was hopeless. But what do you mean by "cheap desktop"?